# What does a Kotlin function signature with T.() mean?

Tags: kotlin

This is a standard Kotlin function (as far as I know)

```
inline fun<T> with(t: T, body: T.() -> Unit) { t.body() }
```

But could anyone write in simple English what does exactly the signature mean? It's a generic function for T, with first argument "t" 
of type T and second, "body" of function type, accepting a function of ???? and returning nothing (Unit)

I see this notation Something.() -> Something is used pretty frequently, i.e. for Anko:

```
inline fun Activity.coordinatorLayout(init: CoordinatorLayout.() -> Unit) = ankoView({ CoordinatorLayout(it) },init)
```

but I don't think it was explained anywhere what .() means...

Comment: it's explained in this answer also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48244734/what-does-classname-mean-in-kotlin

Comment: When I was learning this Kotlin feature, I remembered Groovy's `@Delegate`, and especially `@DelegatesTo` annotations. There is some resemblance.

Answer (score 56, accepted):

`T.() -> Unit` is an extension function type with receiver.

Besides ordinary functions, Kotlin supports extension functions. Such function differs from an ordinary one in that it has a receiver type specification. Here it's a generic `T.` part.

The `this` keyword inside an extension function corresponds to the receiver object (the one that is passed before the dot), so you can call its methods directly (referring to `this` from parent scopes is still possible [with qualifiers](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/this-expressions.html)).

Function `with` is a standard one, yes. It's current code:

```
/**
 * Calls the specified function [block] with the given [receiver] as its receiver and returns its result.
 *
 * For detailed usage information see the documentation for [scope functions](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/scope-functions.html#with).
 */
public inline fun <T, R> with(receiver: T, block: T.() -> R): R = receiver.block()
```

So it's a generic function for `T` and `R`, with first argument "receiver" of type `T` and second, `f` of extension function type, which extends `T`, returning type `R` which in turn returned by the `with`.

For example, you can use it like this:

```
val threadInfoString = with (Thread.currentThread()) {
    // isDaemon() & getPriority() are called with new property syntax for getters & setters
    "${getName()}[isDaemon=$isDaemon,priority=$priority]"
}
```

See documentation for extension functions here:
[kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/lambdas.html#extension-function-expressions](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/lambdas.html#extension-function-expressions)
[kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/scope-functions.html#with](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/scope-functions.html#with)
[kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/extensions.html](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/extensions.html)

---

**Added:**

> So the only valid `f` would be any 0-argument function defined for T?

Not really. In Kotlin [function types and extension function types are unified](http://blog.jetbrains.com/kotlin/2015/04/upcoming-change-function-types-reform/), so that they can be used interchangeably. For example, we can pass String::length where a function `(String) -> Int` is expected.

```
// map() expects `(String) -> Int`
// argument has type `String.() -> Int`
strings.map(String::length)
```

Types like `Thread.() -> String` & `(Thread) -> String` are the same from the background side – receiver, in fact, is the first argument.

So any of the following functions is suitable for `Thread.() -> String` argument:

```
fun main(args: Array<String>) {
    val f1 = fun Thread.(): String = name
    val f2 = fun Thread.() = name
    val f3: Thread.() -> String = { name }
    val f4: (Thread) -> String = { it.name }
    val f5 = { t: Thread -> t.name }
    val f6: (Thread) -> String = Thread::getNameZ
    val f7: Thread.() -> String = Thread::getNameZ
    val f8 = Thread::getNameZ
}

fun Thread.getNameZ() = name
```

Or you can simply use [function literal](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/lambdas.html#function-literal-syntax) (`{}`) as in the example with `threadInfoString`, but it works only when the receiver type can be inferred from the context.

Comment: Thank you for great answer, I had to word each fx myself to understand them. Interestingly learing Scala basics seemed easier :D But maybe one more question - what is the difference between `Class1.() -> Class2` and `(Class1) -> Class2`

Comment: OK, I know - `Class1.() -> Class2` accepts a function and has `this`, while `(Class1) -> Class2` accepts a lambda and has `it`

Comment: @ssuukk yes, you are right – `Class1.() -> Class2` has `this`, while `(Class1) -> Class2` has `it`. Both are interchangeable functions.

Answer (score 16):

This is another amazing concept named Function literals with receiver, It looks similar with extension function with difference that it has **["receiver"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45875491/what-is-a-receiver-in-kotlin)**.

```
inline fun doSomethingWithInt(receiver: Int.() -> Unit) {

    5.receiver() //Possible as receiver is Int type

    receiver(5) //possible as receiver should be passed as first Argument
}
```

Let's break this apart

**`(receiver: Int.() -> Unit)`**

How this is different from Regular lambda like `() -> Unit` is it has receiver which is Type of **`Int`**

So similar to Extension function this receiver can invoke on **Int** type

**`5.receiver()`**

And as per the [Documentation Here](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/lambdas.html#invoking-a-function-type-instance)

> A value of a function type can be invoked by using its invoke(...)
>   operator:
>
> f.invoke(x) or just f(x).
>
> **If the value has a receiver type, the receiver object should be passed
>   as the first argument**. Another way to invoke a value of a function
>   type with receiver is to prepend it with the receiver object, as if
>   the value were an extension function: 1.foo(2)

So You can also write **`receiver(5)`**

Now we can write **DSL style code** because of this. Let's see kotlin standard library function `Apply`

```
public inline fun <T> T.apply(block: T.() -> Unit): T { block(); return this }
```

As you can see apply is an Extension function of T, **block** will be function with receiver type **T**,

**Because of T.()** T will be available as the first argument in lambda.

Now here block is invoked by **block()** inside function body, but you can also write **this.block() or block(this)**

And after invoking this lambda **we will return instance of T(same instance on which apply is called)**

So, what we did in apply is took lambda in argument, executed it on same instance T on which it was called, and return the same T instance

Example

Calling of this function will look like:

```
(StringBuilder("Hello ").apply({ append("Kotliner") }))
```

But in kotlin if lambda is last argument then instead of writing like `funName({})` you can simply write `funName{}`.

so above code can be also written as

```
StringBuilder("Hello ").apply {
        append("Kotliner")
        append("! ")
    }
```

which looks more clear and concise. So this way Kotlin provides DSL structure like Groovy.

This is [very nice blog](https://kotlinexpertise.com/function-literals-with-receiver/) about same Topic

Comment: Thank you for explaining it so well!

Answer (score 0):

It's called "Function literals with receiver"

Function types can optionally have an additional receiver type, which is specified before a dot in the notation: the type A.(B) -> C represents functions that can be called on a receiver object of A with a parameter of B and return a value of C. Function literals with receiver are often used along with these types.

You can found answer in kotlin offical document:[Function literals with receiver](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/lambdas.html#function-literals-with-receiver)